# Contar casos repetidos en SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

No tengo mucha experiencia en SQL y me estoy haciendo un lío para resolver algo que casi seguro no es muy complejo.

Tengo una tabla que tiene una columna con un codigo alphanumerico:

```
columnA {xa1, xa2, xa3, xa3, xa3, xa4, xa4, xa5, xa6, xa6, etc.}
```

Estoy intentando crear una nueva tabla que me diga lo siguiente:

como de xa1, xa2 i xa5 hay 1 en cada caso, tengo 3 sucesos de 1, 1 suceso de 3 repteciones (xa3), 2 sucesos de 2 repeticiones (xa4, xa6).

He conseguido crear la tabla que me dice el numero de sucesos de cada codigo:

```
SELECT   rules.codventa,
     COUNT(rules.codventa) AS sum INTO suma 
FROM     rules 
GROUP BY rules.codventa 
ORDER BY rules.codventa DESC;
```

me queda algo así:

- xa1 -- 1
- xa2 -- 1
- xa3 -- 3
- xa4 -- 2
- xa5 -- 1
- xa6 -- 2

Ahora no consigo obtener la tabla final que me diga:

- 1 -- 3
- 2 -- 2
- 3 -- 1

Alguna idea?

Gracias

EDIT: añado el código de creación de la tabla

```
CREATE TABLE gourmet.rules
(
  codventa character(25) NOT NULL,
  nombretienda character(100) NOT NULL,
  codproducto character(100) NOT NULL,
  unidades smallint NOT NULL,
  precioventa numeric(8,4) NOT NULL
)
```

La clave primaria corresponde a codventa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He conseguido un código que me funciona basandome en la propuesta de Patricio.

```
SELECT   sum,
     COUNT(1)
     FROM (SELECT   rules.codventa,
                    COUNT(rules.codventa) AS sum
                    FROM     rules 
                    GROUP BY rules.codventa 
                    ORDER BY rules.codventa DESC
    )AS tablaFinal
    GROUP BY sum
    ORDER BY sum;
```

Gracias a todos por vuestra ayuda y feliz año nuevo!

Answer (score 1):

Si no te entendí mal, lo que puedes hacer es:

```
SELECT   suma,
         COUNT(1)
         FROM (SELECT   rules.codventa,
                        COUNT(rules.codventa) AS sum INTO suma 
                        FROM     rules 
                        GROUP BY rules.codventa 
                        ORDER BY rules.codventa DESC
        )
        GROUP BY suma;
```

Es decir, tomamos tu consulta original y la usamos como una subconsulta para poder contar los distintos casos de `suma`

Comment: Hola Patricio, he probado tu código, en primer lugar me pide que la subconsulta debe tener un pseudonimo lo qual es facil añadiendo {AS foo} dónde acaba el parentesis. Añadiendo el alias me dice que el INTO no esta permitido dónde se encuentra, alguna idea? Saludos y gracias.

Comment: @alwayslearn: Para corregir lo del `INTO` tendrías que explicar para qué sirve en tu consulta original, lo que no está claro en la pregunta.  Porque si quieres que la consulta corra, puedes quitarlo no mas.

Comment: @sstan tenías razón, ya he publicado la respuesta con el código que me ha dado lo que buscava, gracias por tu tiempo

Answer (score 0):

Si los códigos en "codventa" están en un arreglo se puede usar la función `unnest` para trasformarlo en una pseudotabla:

```
select id, codigo, count(*) as cantidad
  from la_tabla, unnest(codventa) codigo
  group by id, codigo
  order by id, codigo;
```

Esto mostraría los resultados similares a los que ya puedes obtener. Para contar las cantidades usando esa consulta o cualquier otra se la puede poner dentro de otra consulta y usarla como fuente para otro select:

```
select cantidad, count(*) as ocurrencias
  from (
    select id, codigo, count(*) as cantidad
      from la_tabla, unnest(codventa) codigo
      group by id, codigo
      order by id, codigo
  ) x
  group by cantidad
  order by cantidad;
```

Para probar esto usé esta definición de tabla:

```
create table la_tabla(
    id integer primary key,
    codventa text[]
);

insert into la_tabla values
  (1, '{xa1, xa2, xa3, xa3, xa3, xa4, xa4, xa5, xa6, xa6}');
```

#### Resultados

[image: resultados]

### Ejemplo en línea

Acá hay un ejemplo que corre en línea: http://rextester.com/BLR10268

Te recomiendo cuando hagas preguntas intentes en esa página o sqlfiddle o la que prefieras, pongas la definición de tablas sobre la que estés haciendo la pregunta y un ejemplo de datos. Eso nos ayuda a ayudarte.

Comment: Hola Emilio, gracias por el consejo, he añadido el código de creación de la tabla